# PIC16F Timer 2 one shot not running

Tags: pic, one-shot

I am using a PIC16F18877 to control some LEDs on a control panel.  The whole project is rather huge, involving multiple processors communicating via SPI. This particular processor is controlling 88 LEDs in an 11 x 8 matrix arrangement.  Pins RA0-RA7 and RE0-RE2 are providing the 11 (cathode) lines via ULN2803 transistor arrays, data for the LEDs is on Port D.

I want to add simple PWM brightness controls to the LEDs, during the refresh cycles, so I want to use a timer (TMR2) as a one shot timer, feeding this into CCP5 to produce a PWM signal which can be routed to ports A and E, via PPS.

The timer interrupt service routine will then output the data for the appropriate 'column' in the matrix, and start the timer for PWM control.  On the next interrupt, a new column, data and PWM output pin can be selected, the timer re-started, and the process repeats ad nauseum, producing the correct display.

However, I am really struggling to get TMR2 to work in one-shot mode.  As a free running timer, it counts.  As a one-shot it does absolutely nothing.

This is my timer 2 initialization code:

```
START
CALL  Init_TMR2
Main_Loop        ;Just a dummy empty loop for testing Timer2
NOP
NOP
NOP
GOTO Main_Loop

Init_TMR2
    Banksel TMR2
    MOVLW 0xFF
    MOVWF T2PR
    MOVLW 0x40      ;Prescale 16:1
    MOVWF T2CON
    MOVLW 0x01      ;Fosc/4 clock selection
    MOVWF T2CLKCON
    MOVLW 0x08      ;One shot mode, software controlled
    MOVWF T2HLT
    CLRF  T2RST     ;No external reset required - will be done in ISR

    BSF   T2CON.ON  ;Start the timer

    RETURN
```

Checking this in the MPLAB simulator / single stepping and checking TMR2, if I set T2HLT to zero i.e. free running, the timer counts, but with Mode 8 (one shot) it doesn't.

What have I missed?

Comment: Try clearing TMR2?

Comment: Whilst I haven't explicit cleared TMR2 (which might not be a bad idea), the watch list in the debugger showed that it was set to 0x00 i.e. clear, and not incrementing, which is how I knew it wasn't doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

So to sum up.  Always Always Always set TxCON LAST.  The setup order of the other timer registers DOES MATTER but it depends upon the timer mode.

When in one-shot mode, the timer DOES NOT set the interrupt flag.

As a result I had to find a different way of solving the problem - details given in my other posts.

Thanks to Ian Bland and James for your contributions.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for coming back after you solved your problem. You said: "*details given in my other posts*". Please can you [Edit] your answer and include the details *here* in your answer (yes, even if that means just doing a copy & paste :-) ). Comments, that I think you are are referring to, are different from other types of post here on SE - they are for temporary information only and should not be treated as permanent. (See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756).)  In fact they can disappear without you, or the moderators, deleting them! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Then, when you have added the details into the answer to make it complete, please mark the whole topic as solved, by "accepting" your answer (click the "tick mark" next to your answer, to turn it green). Then it is shown as having an accepted answer in various lists, and we don't get nagged for it being a question with an unaccepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you are doing Banksel TMR2. In the Timer2 section of the data sheet it does actually refer to the TMR2 register yet in the Memory Map Bank documentation early in the data sheet it refers to that register as T2TMR. If you are using the wrong name then you are possibly not switching to the correct bank.

You could try Banksel T2TMR and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Good call James, I tried changing it, but it made no difference.  Looking at the op-codes the compiler created, was also no change.  It does seem as if TMR2 = T2TMR in the compiler.

Comment: I have also found another problem, in that when in one-shot mode TMR2 does NOT generate an interrupt so my whole methodology of the bigger picture will not work...I found this out by using the XC8 compiler and MCC - which did get the timer to run in one-shot...

Comment: It seems that setting T2CON before any of the other registers is unreliable - in free running mode it seems ok, but in other modes T2CON MUST be setup last.  In fact the order that ALL the registers are done seems to be important.  I copied the order MCC does it, and tried re-arranging the order for different timer modes in assembler, and sometimes they worked and sometimes they didn't...

Comment: Anyway, I have resolved my problem on several fronts - the timer wasn't working because register order is important.   When it was working it doesn't produce an interrupt flag in one-shot mode, verified in mcc as well.  So I have come up with a seemingly convoluted but functional way of doing my original idea.  Using PWM7 to generate the timing signal, but at twice the desired frequency.  Feed this into CLC1 which is set up as a divide-by-2 (toggling a Flip-Flop).  Feed the output of CLC1 and PWM7 into CLC2 and AND them together.  Feed CLC2 into CWG3 and steer the outputs onto the ports.

Comment: Use an interrupt on the falling edge of CLC2 to change the data and the active port pin via RxyPPS.

This convoluted mother-of-god-how-complicated-can-this-get solution actually damn well worked!  There is a minor glitch that I can live with - when writing to LATA (or any LATx for that matter) the Logic Analyser shows a negative edge one instruction cycle glitch on the port pins if the output is to be held high.  This COULD just be a simulator glitch I hope, and not manifest in the silicon, but I can live with it even if it does.  I will measure it on a scope and find out when I build it,.